# Java program fails with Oracle jdbc driver package doesn't exist in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, oracle, ubuntu, jdbc, jar

I have read a number of solutions posted here about this, but I can't seem to get the database connected for some reason. Here is my code first.

Note: The url, user and passwd have been deleted just for my privacy.

Also am I forgetting to import something in my java code?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class test
{
    String createTableString = "create table dummy (count int)";
    String insertIntoTableString = "insert into dummy values (2)";
    String selectTableString = "select * from dummy";
    String url="-----";
    String user = "-----";
    String passwd = "-----";
    String result = "";

    public test()
    {
        System.out.println("Accessing oracle database....");
    } // end constructor

    public void getResults()
    {
        try
        {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver()); 
            System.err.println("Done with driver registrations!");
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("cant find the driver.");
        }

        try{
            System.out.println("Trying to connect...");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,passwd);
            System.out.println("Connection successful");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            stmt.executeQuery(createTableString); // No need to return anything for creating table

            stmt.executeQuery(insertIntoTableString);

            insertIntoTableString = "insert into dummy values (20)";
            stmt.executeQuery(insertIntoTableString);

            insertIntoTableString = "insert into dummy values (2098)";
            stmt.executeQuery(insertIntoTableString);

            insertIntoTableString = "insert into dummy values (34)";
            stmt.executeQuery(insertIntoTableString);

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectTableString); // returns table with metadata

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                result += rs.getString(1)+" ";
                result += "\n";
            }
            System.out.println("\n"+result);
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        test obj = new test();
        obj.getResults();
    }
}
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I have only installed java just now, so I don't know if I have to install something else.

I tried compiling it using `javac test.java` but if fails with an error saying

```
test.java:25: error: package oracle.jdbc.driver does not exist
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver()); 
                                                               ^
1 error
```

Like someone said on another SO question, i tried compiling it using `javac -classpath ".;/home/path-till-jar/ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar;" test.java` but it fails with the same error as above. The `ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar` was a file that I got from some site. I don't know if that's the right jar as it was extremely difficult to figure out which jar file to download since there is no good source online.

Comment: You should get the jar from your oracle installation. And Ubuntu 16.10 is not a LTS release. **And**, the classpath separator on Linux is `:` (not `;`). So, `".:/home/path-till-jar/ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar;"`

Comment: Oops, my bad meant it to be 16.04. And that class separator thing noted, but where do I get my jar from?

Comment: I tried changing the `;` to `:` and it compiles but now I am getting an error called ClassNotFoundException

Comment: This is the exact issue, place your Oracle JDBC jar into your CLASSPATH to solve your issue.

Comment: It compiles but I get a run time error called Class not found exception.

Comment: The way you load the JDBC driver **is wrong**. For a JDBC 4 (or higher) driver you usually don't need to load it, and if you do need to load it, you should be using `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")` instead. Calling `DriverManager.registerDriver` is something only JDBC drivers themselves should do (which they do from a static initializer when the class gets loaded and initialized).

Comment: BTW: If it compiles fine, but fails on run, then you have the driver on the compile time classpath, but not on the run time classpath.